# SQL - How to get the sum of 3 leading values greater than the current value in a different column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with data as shown below
[image]

The output that I want is in the last column which is essentially the `sum(value for next 3 leading value)` for month_diff greater than current value i.e. the value `33` in the first row is the `sum(Value) for month_diff>0 i.e. 1-3` and similarly 7th row `22` is `sum(values) for month_diff between 1-3`. So on and so forth.

It has to be partition by the id columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, you want a window frame specification:

```
select t.*,
       sum(value) over (partition by id1, id2
                        order by month_diff
                        rows between 1 following and 3 following
                       ) as desired_output
from t;
```

If you want to be sure that you actually have three values, then you need some `case` logic:

```
select t.*,
       (case when lead(id1, 3) over (partition by id1, id2 order by month_diff) is not null
             then sum(value) over (partition by id1, id2
                                   order by month_diff
                                   rows between 1 following and 3 following
                                  )
        end) as desired_output
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
select *, 
  if(count(*) over win = 3, sum(value) over win, 0) output
from `project.dataset.tabel`
window win as (
  partition by id1, id2 
  order by month_diff 
  rows between 1 following and 3 following
)
```